# Creating a Window with a Rectangle in it with C++ and SDL2

Tags: c++, sdl-2, mingw32

When i want to create a window using SDL2 and C++ with the following Code:

```
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <time.h>
using namespace std;

const int SCREEN_WIDTH = 800;
const int SCREEN_HEIGHT = 600;
const int FPS = 60;


bool quit = false;

SDL_Window* window = NULL;
SDL_Renderer* renderer = NULL;

SDL_Rect player = {0, 0, 10, 10};

int init(){
    if( SDL_Init( SDL_INIT_VIDEO ) < 0 ){
        cout<<"SDL could not be initialized! SDL_Error: "<<SDL_GetError();
        return 1;
    }
    else{
        window = SDL_CreateWindow(
            "SDL Tutorial",
            SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED,
            SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED,
            SCREEN_WIDTH,
            SCREEN_HEIGHT,
            SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN);
        if( window == NULL ){
            //printf( "Window could not be created! SDL_Error: %s\n", SDL_GetError() );
            return 1;
        }
        else{
            return 0;
        }
    }

    renderer = SDL_CreateRenderer(window, -1, SDL_RENDERER_ACCELERATED | SDL_RENDERER_PRESENTVSYNC);
    SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, 255, 255, 255, 255);

}

void Events(){

    SDL_Event event;

    while(SDL_PollEvent( &event ) != 0) {

        //User requests quit
        if( event.type == SDL_QUIT ){
            quit = true;
        }

        if(event.type == SDL_MOUSEMOTION){
            player.x = event.motion.x;
            player.y = event.motion.y;
        }

        else if(event.type == SDL_KEYDOWN){

            //Select surfaces based on key press
            switch( event.key.keysym.sym ) {
                case SDLK_UP:
                cout<<"Pfeiltaste nach oben wurde gedrückt!"<<endl;
                break;

                case SDLK_DOWN:
                cout<<"Pfeiltaste nach unten wurde gedrückt!"<<endl;
                break;

                case SDLK_LEFT:
                cout<<"Pfeiltaste nach links wurde gedrückt!"<<endl;
                break;

                case SDLK_RIGHT:
                cout<<"Pfeiltaste nach rechts wurde gedrückt!"<<endl;
                break;

                case SDLK_ESCAPE:
                quit = true;
                break;

                default:
                cout<<"Irgendeine Taste wurde gedrückt"<<endl;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}

void Loop(){

    while(!quit){
        //Events:
        Events();

        //<Game-Code>



        //</Game-Code>
        //<Draw-Code>
        SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, 255, 255, 255, 255);
        if (SDL_RenderClear(renderer)!=0) {
            cout<<"Fehler: "<<SDL_GetError()<<endl;
        }

        SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, 255, 0, 0, 255);
        SDL_RenderFillRect(renderer, &player);

        SDL_RenderPresent(renderer);
        //</Draw-Code>
    }

}

void Cleanup(){

    SDL_DestroyRenderer(renderer);
    renderer = NULL;

    SDL_DestroyWindow(window);
    window = NULL;

    SDL_Quit();

}

int main( int argc, char* args[] ){

    if(init() != 0){
        cerr<<"Ein Fehler ist bei der Initialisierung aufgetreten!"<<endl;
    }

    Loop();

    Cleanup();
    return 0;
}
```

then it just creates a window with my current windows appearing on my desktop:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/NSPJR.jpg

I have no clue, of what i am doing wrong, please help me ;-)

I know the code is not the best, but i hope it's understandable xD

Comment: Check return value of `SDL_CreateRenderer()`, it may be null. Also, you should replace that crappy `if` chain in `Events()` with `switch (event.type) {...}`. Or with `if (...) {...} else if (...) {...}`, but it's worse than switch in this case.

Comment: Thanks for your fast Reply, i tested if the return value is null; it's not xD
I also cleaned the crappy If-Statements you mentioned. But I have no solution for my problem :/

Comment: But SDL_RenderClear(renderer) is not working and SDL_GetError() gives me an Error with the content:"Invalid Renderer".

Comment: I tested it again and its 0, but i don't know why

Comment: Try to call `SDL_GetError()` right after renderer creation.

Comment: I appreciate your help, but i fixed the error already: in the init() function there was an else-statement with return 0, so the compiler doesn't reach the renderer = ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the error, in the init() function i had an else statement which returns 0, thus the program never reaches the renderer = SDL_CreateRenderer()
But again thanks for your help ;-)